# find element inside jquery object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to use `find()` method to look for a specific div inside jquery object, but all i've got is an error message "find is not a function". What do I do wrong?

Here is my script:

```
$('.show-more-news').on('click', function() {
  $.get('/news?page=2', function($news_page) {
    $('.more-news-mobile').append($news_page.find('grid_9'));
  });
});
```

Comment: `$news_page` is not a jQuery object. `$news_page` is the response received from the server, which is typically a string.

Comment: $news_page isn't a jquery element, it's returning the data from the get https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/.  The find method can only be run on a jquery element like $("#id").find("grid_9")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap your $new_page with $() like this to convert to jQuery object:

```
$($news_page).find('grid_9')
```